# Google Analytics Array decode foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, google-analytics-api

Hi this is my first foray into the wonderful world of Google Analytics and their API and I have hit a road bump and wondered if someone could help.

I am retrieving the following array:

```
[
    [
     "iPhone",
     "United Kingdom",
     "51.5073",
     "-0.1277",
     "1",
     "18"
    ],
    [
     "iPhone",
     "Australia",
     "-33.8675",
     "151.2070",
     "1",
     "17"
    ],
    [
     "iPhone",
     "United Kingdom",
     "51.5171",
     "-0.1461",
     "5",
     "16"
    ]
]
```

this is being output to my page using the standard (demo based htmlOutput function) I am getting the data using this call in the

> coreReportingApiReference.php

PHP:

```
  private function getRows($results) {
    $json;
    if(count($results->getRows()) > 0) {
        $json .= json_encode($results->getRows());
    } else {
        $json .= '<p>No results found.</p>';
    }
        return $json;
  }
```

I want to know how to - in a foreach loop get hold of each one of these objects in the outputted "array" and work with them in my page. At this point eve just running a count() on the output is return only 1.

My end goal is to use this data in a map overlay and some charts.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
foreach($data as $row) {
  list($item, $country, $lat, $long, $number1, $number2) = $row;
  echo "$item was purchased in $country, at $lat x $long, with data $number1 and $number2\n";
}
```

Comment: It returns blank when I use it like this `foreach($htmlOutput as $row) {list($item, $country, $lat, $long, $number1, $number2) = $row; echo "$item was purchased in $country, at $lat x $long, with data $number1 and $number2\n";`

Comment: It should work if `$data` is the array you dumped in the question. This just echoes the data, if you want to do something else with it replace that part of the loop with whatever you want to do.

Comment: can get the code highlighter to work in comments either really annoying

Comment: ok thanks for that, this is where iI wonder if it is an array at all then beacuse it doesn't respond like one ought to

Comment: I've used Google Analytics, its output is a multi-dimensional array. Some parts are indexed, some parts are associative.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28394/discussion-between-justin-erswell-and-barmar)